# Run Java app on Mesos without Docker

Tags: java, jvm, mesos

I'm just figuring out Mesos and testing it on a vagrant node.
While in the process of checking out mesos, my work ran into the JVM memory leak in Docker issue posted here -> https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15020

I would like to know if there are some tips or examples where we can test the containerization on Mesos to see if the memory problems are specific to Docker Containerizers. So far most of the examples are for marathon running docker, but not much else on non-docker Mesos.

1. Do I need to write my own Mesos JVM Containerizer Isolator?
2. Do containerizer just parse job details, and executes a script?
3. Can I pass the Mesos containerizer a .war and job package and have it run my Java App?
4. Any simple samples or specific code on large github projects that illustrates this?

My work is deciding if we should deploy our Java apps without containerization or if changing a containerization solution may help resolve the issue.

Any tips or links to documentation I can check to look at how to setup a Tomcat JVM app on Mesos Containerizers?  I am still learning how mesos works, so anything helps!

Comment: I never tried it, but I doubt that you can easily run a Tomcat app without Docker. I guess a Spring Boot app would be a better solution...

Comment: That is what my preliminary digging seems to imply ... its still workable, if Marathon + Mesos can easily restart services with no downtime, but this makes it harder to convince people to commit to it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let me step back a bit: you don't run a Java app on Mesos, you run it on one of its frameworks, such as Marathon (for long-running tasks such as a webserver) or Chronos (for scheduled batch jobs). Think of Mesos as the Linux kernel of a distributed operating system, that might help.

Coming back to your question, and unless you plan to [write your own framework](https://opencredo.com/write-mesos-framework/) (for example [tobilg/mesos-js-framework](https://github.com/tobilg/mesos-js-framework)), the following assumes you use Marathon to launch Tomcat (since it is a long-running task).

Marathon, as most frameworks, doesn't do the heavy lifting, [it leverages](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/src/main/scala/mesosphere/mesos/TaskBuilder.scala) Mesos core features such as the [Fetcher](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/fetcher/) to pull resources necessary to [execute an app](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html) into the sandbox on the Mesos Agent. Via `uris` you can specify a list of URLs that Marathon (via the Mesos Fetcher) downloads and, depending on the file extension, also extracts before it launches the app specified via the content of `cmd`.

Comment: So if I specify the Mesos containerizer to Mesos and omit Docker, then Marathon will execute my Java package inside the Mesos containerizer solution... this would be a way to test Java within the Mesos default sandbox solution?